# handling props in a deconstructed child

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a React component  that clones its children with additional props. I'm using the standard childrenWithProps method that works great if your child is another react component but no clear way of doing this without a direct react component as the child.

```
<DataCmp>
   <Fragment>
      <h1>Example Code</h1>
      <div>{isLoggedIn}</div>
   </Fragment>
</DataCmp>
```

In this example, I have  adding the prop `myData` to the props of its children. However, this doesn't work. The child doesn't see the value. It will say myData is not set when it's passed in by props.

So I attempted this:

```
<DataCmp>
   <Fragment>
      <h1>Example Code</h1>
      <div>{this.props.isLoggedIn}</div>
   </Fragment>
</DataCmp>
```

This brings up errors as it has no idea what `this.props.myData` is.

My next attempt was to wrap the child in an inline function and get the prop from that.

```
<DataCmp>
  {({ isLoggedIn}) => (
   <Fragment>
      <h1>Example Code</h1>
      <div>{isLoggedIn}</div>
   </Fragment>
  )}
</DataCmp>
```

While this doesn't bring up any errors; The child component is never rendered.

I'm working on updating and modernizing someone else old Github project. here is the [link to my project](https://github.com/Patrick-W-McMahon/token_sale) and the wrapping component is [Wallet.jsx](https://github.com/Patrick-W-McMahon/token_sale/blob/main/src/components/wallet.jsx) the location that it's being used is [index.jsx](https://github.com/Patrick-W-McMahon/token_sale/blob/main/src/pages/index.jsx)

The children are rendered as such:

```
renderChildren = () => {
        const { children } = this.props;
        const { accounts } = this.state;
        const handleLogin = () => this.login();
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
            if(typeof child == 'object') {
                return React.cloneElement(child, {
                    key: index,
                    loginFn: () => handleLogin(),
                    isLoggedIn: accounts[0] !== '0x0',
                    accounts,
                });
            } else {
                return child;
            }   
        });
        return childrenWithProps;
    }
```

Comment: In theory the third option is correct. If the child does not get rendered there is an issue with your DataCmp. Can you share the code?

Comment: I updated the question to include links to the Github repo that I'm working on. I'm attempting to build an updated reconstruction of someone else's project from 3 years ago.

Comment: I see, thanks! The issue is with your usage of `React.Children.map`, which only iterates over values that qualify as valid react element. You can test this with `React.isValidElement(el)`. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `React.Children.map(children, fn)` only iterates over valid react elements

This excludes, for example, functions passed as child. Passing a function-to-be-rendered as prop to a component is known as [Render Props pattern](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). React.Children.map will not iterate over this, hence, your third option returned `null`.

Fix it by checking whether `children` is a valid ReactElement first and render it accordingly:

```js
// wallet.tsx
...
const additionalProps = { ... };
if (React.isValidElement(children)) {
  return React.Children.map(children,
    (child, i) => React.cloneElement(child, { key: i, ...additionalProps });
} else {
  // handle null, strings, undefined, booleans etc
  return typeof children === 'function' ? children(additionalProps) : children;
}
...

// index.tsx

<Wallet ...>
  {/* either a function */}
  {(additionalProps) => console.log(additionalProps)}

  {/* or components */}
  <Layout>
    ...
  </Layout>
</Wallet>
```

Note that `React.isValidElement()` also returns true for HTML-Elements. Which will receive the props but you obviously cannot add custom-logic. But let's say you pass a `style` props, it will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the error may not be in the destructuring, but in how you are using `childrenWithProps`.

It would be useful if you shared a condesandbox representing the problem with dummy data, so we can take a look there at that part too.

Comment: I have included links to my GitHub where the source code is located.